# why an empty array gets printed out when trying to split a string using split(".")

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm experimenting with String class's instance method split(). However, when I use `.` as split() method's argument and trying to print it out using `Arrays.toString(s2)`, only an empty array gets printed out.

Why is this happening?

```
String s1 = "hello.world";
String[] s2 = s1.split(".");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This " *weird*"  behavior is because you are not scaping the dot in the regex... i.e you need to do `s1.split("\\.");` and not s`1.split(".");`

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hello.world";
        String[] s2 = s1.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2));
}
```

just for the learning process the dot in the regex belongs to the known metacharacters and every time you try to use regexwith them they must be scaped...

take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) for more info...

> there are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the
>   caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or
>   pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus
>   sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), and the
>   opening square bracket [, the opening curly brace {, These special
>   characters are often called "metacharacters".

Comment: why do I have to use escape \ here? Could you please point me out to some articles  or documentation regarding this? Thanks again for your help

Comment: done... a list of those special characters is in the update and a link to a tutorial too

Answer (score 2):

As per the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), the `split` method takes a regular expression as argument. It so happens that in regular expression syntax, the period means *any character*, thus you are splitting on every character, which is why you are getting the empty array.

To fix this, you will need to escape the period like so: `.split("\\.")`. The extra `\` instructs the regex engine to treat the period as an actual character, devoid of any special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape special characters using these methods

1.String test = "abc.xyz";
String[] output1 = test.split("\.");

2.String test = "abc.xyz";
String[] output2 = test.split(Pattern.quote("."));

You can refer to
[split a string](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-split-a-string/)

Answer (score 1):

. is a special char in regex and split accepts regex as param, you should escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
 String[] s2 = s1.split("\\.");
```

There are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, and the opening square bracket `[`, the opening curly brace `{`, These special characters are often called "metacharacters".

If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash. In literal Java strings the backslash is an escape character. The literal string `"\\"` is a single backslash.